# A short word for elementary yet interesting

Tags: single-word-requests

What can be a one word for something which is not very advanced but is still interesting and elegant? I would be using this word in context for some math article I want to write.

Shorter and accurate words would be preferred. Thanks :)

Comment: _Elegant_ is the word mathematicians would use, and shorter is almost always more elegant, provided the same generalizations are captured -- and whenever possible proven -- as in any longer version.

Comment: @JohnLawler Elegant however, generally does not refer to elementary I think.

Comment: The most elegant proof I've ever seen is Euclid's on the infinity of primes. And it's one of the most elementary.

Comment: [**Elegance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegance) *is a synonym for **beautiful** that has come to acquire the additional connotations of unusual **effectiveness and simplicity**.* And in OP's context we can reasonably suppose that ***beautiful = interesting***.

Comment: How about 'logical'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might say it has *elegant simplicity.*

Answer (score 5):

Consider **neat** as in "a neat proof."

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics both **integral** [below] and **functional** could be used for a core mathematics class.

> necessary to make a whole complete; essential or fundamental.

Comment: This is not what I mean actually. I meant mathematics which is not very advanced, which doesn't relate to how easy it might be. Infact, it might not be effortless at all.

Comment: I would update your question.  Elementary math is really easy for most.

Comment: In physics and other sciences, "fundamental" is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, clear, and synonyms thereof.

Comment: I think that this doesn't describe the interest in the subject. If I say that something is simple it usually means that it doesn't interest me.

Answer (score 1):

Visually pleasing, less brainstorming, cleaner, slim, easily digestive, simple, etc.

Comment: *Less brainstorming* and *easily digestive* sound odd. Shouldn't the second be *digestible* or *easily digested*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the comment. Sure your makes more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Elemental](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elemental)** means basic and important; having the power of a force of nature.

The word conveys the sense that there is something essential or significant, while at the same time being basic or simple.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "tidy"?  As in "We can build upon this **tidy** conclusion by ..."

I agree with @MattEckert that "neat" would be good, but I some younger readers might confuse it for the colloquial "neat-o".  You could convert that to an adverb:  "This **neatly** illustrates the point that ..."

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps *economical?* it can be used to refer to proofs as having few steps, but still has a positive connotation (if not one of elegance, per se).

Comment: Umm, I dont see how it relates to being not very advanced or interesting.